# How to check if there exists a key in an array that contains a certain string in php?

Tags: php, arrays, web, web-applications

I am working on a webapp right now in PHP. So far there is a defined array with the following structure:

```
$array = array("check_first" => true, "check_second" => false)
```

There are also much other arrays with default numerical structure with keys: 0, 1,2,3 etc.

I want now to make a difference between the arrays with keys of numerical and arrays with keys of strings that starts with "check_".

So I would like to search through all my defined arrays if there is a array with keys that contains the string "check_". I would prefer a simple if-statement for this.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks for all your comments!

Comment: What do you want the result to be?  You say _difference between the arrays with keys of nummerical and arrays with keys of strings that starts with "check_"_ so what is the numerical array and what do you want the difference result to be?

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: loop through the array with `foreach`
- Step2 for each entry, check if the key starts with your string using `strpos($key, 'check_')!==false`

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to get all the array keys, concatenate them into a single string, then use strpos to test if athere are any instances of 'check_'.

```
if (strpos(implode('',array_keys($arr)),'check_') !== false) {
    echo 'This array has "check_" keys!';
}
```

Although this is coded concisely it includes three function calls, two of which are applied to all of the array elements. A foreach loop that breaks on the first match may be faster.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer